# SPF problems with Google Apps

Tags: email, spf, email-bounces, amazon-ses

I currently have an SPF record with a hostname of @ that is:

```
v=spf1 mx ip4:x.x.x.243/32 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all
```

I also have another record of"

```
spf2.0/pra mx ip4:x.x.x.243/32 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all
```

We have had a lot of email being bounced back because of spam and now when I go to http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html? and check the "Does my domain already have an SPF record? What is it? Is it valid?" it says no spf record exists.

However, when I send an email using our Amazon SES script and check the headers it says it passes the SPF test.

Is there something I am missing?  Do I need to place that text in quotes ""?  Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to place that text in quotes ""?

The missing quotes should be the problem indeed, as explained e.g. in [Record Types Supported](http://dyn.com/support/record-types-standard-dns/):

> Unlike with most other record types, for TXT records the Data field is
>   essentially free-form and may even include spaces. Please note: When
>   entering a string that includes spaces, such as SPF records, you must
>   enclose the string in double quotes; otherwise, individual words will
>   be separately quoted and break up the record into multiple parts.

Here are the records we currently use successfully for [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) as per [Authenticating Your Email Address](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SPFSenderIDDKIM.html) (it's indeed unfortunate that their documentation doesn't address the quoting needs):

```
"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"
"spf2.0/pra include:amazonses.com ~all"
```

Your records should simply look like so accordingly:

```
"v=spf1 mx ip4:x.x.x.243/32 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all"
"spf2.0/pra mx ip4:x.x.x.243/32 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all"
```